# How do I make glowing line?

Tags: effects

I have a question here.

I'm doing an animation where there's a glowing line coming out from a globe (like what in the video down below), but i don't know how to do the exact effect in Blender.
[Glowing Line](http://sendvid.com/7uiqkcwc)

I tried some glowing shader on a curve but how do I make the line move from spot to spot? do i have to make a trace or something? thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Animating the front of the curve

Assuming, as you say, that you have already created your Bezier Curve, all you need to do is:

- make sure that the Curve has a *Fill Type = Full* and a *Bevel Depth* greater than zero
- animate the *Bevel End* value using keyframes, from 0 at the start frame to 1 at the end frame.

[image]

### Shading

You say that you have already found a shading solution. Let me share my solution anyway:

- Enable "Use UV for mapping" in the Curve properties.
- Use this node setup (the "Add" node is from "Converter > Vector Math").

  [image]
- Animate the *Y* coordinate of the *Combine XYZ* node. This will allow you to create the moving blobs of light along the line.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing demonstration! That is very clear and well-explained!! I learned a lot from you and thank you a lot! :-)
May I have another question here? Can I remove the shadow of the curve on other objects?

Comment: Glad it helped! For the shadow, there is a "Ray Visibility" panel in the "Object" properties window. Uncheck "shadow": done!

Comment: You are a lifesaver, Nicola! Thank you so much :-)